# Is there a UI unit test framework that can test interactions with modal dialogs (via showModalDialog)?

Tags: unit-testing, user-interface, modal-dialog

I'm trying to do some unit/integration tests between pages of my ASP.NET site but can't seem to find any tool that can work effectively with modal dialogs generated by the `showModalDialog` command ([FF3](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.showModalDialog), [IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.showModalDialog)).

Does anyone have experience testing these annoying things?

---

**Update:** @bbmud was right--WatiN supports modal dialogs very well. [Here's the example](http://www.teknologika.com/blog/modal-dialogs-and-dropdowns-in-watin/) that got me started.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you bound to any specific platform? From your questions and answers I am guessing C#/.NET ;)

[WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/index.html) has a good support for modal and modeless dialogs in IE, but I'm not sure whether it works for FF3.

Comment: good assumptions--I'll check it out, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I second WatiN if you are looking for something free.